# How to get element in specific index from NSMutable dictionary (Swift 3)

Tags: swift3, nsmutabledictionary

I need to get the first element from NSMutable dictionary. I tried to get the element using for loop. but I am not getting the correct element because the Dictionary does not follow order. Is there any way I can get the element?

Here is my code:

```
 for (count, i) in myMutableDict.enumerated() {

     if count == 2 {
            print(i.key)
          }
     }
```

Comment: because dictionary is un-ordered. You need to fetch value using key not index.

Comment: There is no first element in a dictionary. That _does not exist_. Do you mean the first element inserted into the dictionary? There does not exist a way to get that either, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

As you know dictionary is un ordered collection Type.

```
    let dictionary:Dictionary = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"];

    for(index,obj) in dictionary.enumerated() {
        print("index- \(index) - Object- \(obj)");
        print("key- \(obj.key) - value- \(obj.value)");
    }
```

Enumeration will provide you `index` and `Objects` of dictionary as above code says. If you want to work with index then you need to get all keys and keep it sorted so that you can get your key by providing index. And from that key you can get value from dictionary object. Piece of code is given below.

```
    var keyList = Array(dictionary.keys);
    keyList = keyList.sorted();

    print("keyList \(keyList)");
    let keyAtIndex = keyList[1];
    print("value = \(dictionary[keyAtIndex]!)");
```

Comment: It did not work for me. Instead, I had to create an array of keys before adding the elements to dictionary.  Thanks for the help anyway